# Car making a weird noise

Tags: engine-knock

My husband hit 115 mph in our 2013 Hyundai Senada it shut off but started right back up and drove fine. We went home in about an hour later went to take it to the store was doing about 55 mph and all of a sudden the car lost power we had to Coast into a parking lot. When you start it now it’s making a pecking or knocking noise in the engine. What do you think this is? We have checked and there is fresh oil in it and none has leaked out overnight.

Comment: Mileage, maintenance performed, parts replaced? Fuel pressure ever checked? Fuel filter ever replaced? Sudden loss of pressure is difficult to see unless a fuel pressure gauge is connected and left in place for the next random engine die off. Pressure usually remains high after engine shut down then bleeds off. Pressure randomly dropping out is seen immediately after engine shutdown whether in the driveway or when it occurs on the road but only with a f/p gauge left connected. If not a fuel issue then maybe loose/worn/corroded electrical connections on a sensor or two in the EFI system.

Answer (score 0):

Could be any number of things but I have seen a couple of Hyundais/Kias with connecting rod bearing issues.  They make a fairly loud knocking noise that comes from the front of the engine.

This, of course, is a serious problem that will require a rebuild or engine replacement.  Hopefully that's not it.

Check for other things that might be making noise such as water pump, alternator, power steering pump, A/C compressor.

You may want to take it to a reputable shop if you're not familiar with auto repairs and how to diagnose problems.